# I will help you now, if you will help me tomorrow. Is it correct/possible?

Tags: grammaticality

does that make sense, according to 'one author'?

If you help me now, I will see you later. (help first, see later). **correct**.

I will see you now, **if you will help** me later (see first, help later). **Is it correct?**

If you helped me now, I would see you later. **correct**.

I would see you now, **if you would help** me later. (same as before: see first, help later). **Is it possible?**

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including the first (optional) ***will*** in constructions like *If you [will] do this, I will do that* is primarily an indicator of ***willingness***, rather than a future tense marker.

Usually you can only include that first ***will*** if it would make sense to use *[BE] **willing** [infinitive]* instead of ***will*** [tensed verb]. Failure to observe this "rule" is common among native speakers of some other languages, so it's something of a [shibboleth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth) indicating "non-native Anglophone"...

> 1: *If you will help me [then] I will pay you*
>    is okay because
>    *If you **are willing to help**...*
>    is a reasonable alternative.
>
> 2: *If you will cry [then] I will dry your tears*
>    is NOT okay because
>    *If you **are willing to cry**...*
>    isn't a natural thing to say.

In principle, using ***would*** instead of ***will*** in such contexts amplifies the "hypothetical" aspect of the possible future action. But in practice it's usually just a conventional marker of deference / politeness.

---

As OP has correctly noted, it's often okay to use Simple Past *If you **helped** me I would pay you* for the IF-clause (in which case the THEN-clause *must* be explicitly marked as "hypothetical", using ***would*** not ***will***). Note that this Simple Past usage is more likely where the IF-clause represents *an alternative to the current situation*, rather than *something that might happen in the future*, but this isn't always the case. For example,...

> *If you helped them tomorrow, they would pay you next week*

...is perfectly idiomatic to many if not most native speakers.